# How to set up a Macro/Hotkey to convert or batch convert PDF to word (with OCR)?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, macros, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I frequently (like 10+ times a day) need to convert pdf's to word. I use the "Save as" feature in Acrobat Pro. Is there any good way to speed up this process, and boil it down to one click? Ideally, a way that doesn't also tie up adobe while processing (i.e. freeze me out of other options).

Best case would be a simple right click option on the file, but I'd be thankful for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow run script at powershell, type at `cmd` run as Administrator:

Select pin `cmd` press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right mouse Click</kbd>

[image]

[image]

```
powershell -command "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned"
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Create folder PdfConvert at Desktop, Run `Pdf2Docx4.cmd`

[image]

## Convert all pdf file at folder $PDFpath :) to docx.

Pdf2Docx4.cmd:

```
powershell .\PdfConvert\Pdf2Docx4.ps1
```

Pdf2Docx4.ps1:

```
$TypeExt="docx"
$closeDocParam = $true;
$PDFpath = "D:\VBS\PS-29-AcrobatProX\"

Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf |Where {

# logical document

    $AVDoc = New-Object -ComObject AcroExch.AVDoc;    
    
    $AVDoc.Open($_.Fullname, "") | Out-Null;
# physical document

    $PDDoc = $AVDoc.GetPDDoc();                           
    $JavaScriptObject = $PDDoc.GetJSObject();                        
# get the bridge JavaScript Object

    $T = $JavaScriptObject.GetType();

    $T.InvokeMember("SaveAs",

        [Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod -bor `
            [Reflection.BindingFlags]::Public       -bor `
            [Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance          ,

        $null,
        $JavaScriptObject,
        @([IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.Fullname, $TypeExt), ("com.adobe.acrobat."+$TypeExt)));

        $T.InvokeMember("closeDoc", 
 
        [Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod -bor `
            [Reflection.BindingFlags]::Public       -bor `
            [Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance          ,

            $null, 
            $JavaScriptObject, 
            $closeDocParam) | Out-Null;

    $PDDoc.Close()  | Out-Null;
    $AVDoc.Close(1) | Out-Null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This looks like its likely the best answer, but now I've got some learning to do about power shell.

I'll confirm this as the correct answer asap (once i learn enough PS to make it run).

Comment: @Jake OS version?

Comment: Windows 8.1 up to date.

Comment: @Jake Update, write if have problem)

Comment: I am so happy right now. That was incredible. This is seriously such a HUGE help for me. Thank You. Incredibly grateful. Going to pay it forward somehow.